# Swapping values between two keys in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I'm trying to make a new dict based on other dict, however the new dict key value need to be the values of a different key.
I tried to do something like that:

```
dict1 = {'red: ['1'], 'blue': ['2']}
new_dict = dict1.copy()
new_dict.pop('blue')
new_dict.append['red':['1','2']]
```

it didnt work a I thought and now I'm here seeking for help, TY!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "didn't work"? What happens when you run the code? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See also [ask].

Answer (score 0):

```
dict1 = {'red': ['1'], 'blue': ['2']}
new_dict = dict1.copy()
new_dict.pop('blue')
new_dict['red'] = ['1', '2']

print(dict1)
print(new_dict)

# OUTPUT
# {'red': ['1'], 'blue': ['2']}
# {'red': ['1', '2']}
```

Why are you trying to copy the old dict? eventually you are creating a new dict altogether?

Answer (score 0):

when you call the append method you use "append[] ..."- with square-brackets this won't work!
you can try:

```
dict1 = {'red': ['1'], 'blue': ['2']}
new_dict = dict1.copy()
new_dict.pop('blue')
new_dict.update ={'red': ['1','2']}
```

which is useful on dictionaries.
that should return:

```
new_dict
Out: {'red': ['1', '2']}
```

tough you can simply add the "blue" value to the "red" value by:

```
dict1 = {'red': ['1'], 'blue': ['2']}
new_dict.update({'red': ['1', dict1.get('blue')]})

#OUTPUT
new_dict
# {'red': ['1', ['2']]}
```